# At least as many ~

Tags: mathematics, quantifiers

I saw a sentence 
*"Somebody walks from one classroom into a different classroom with **at least as many** students in it."*
(It was part of a math problem)

What does "at least as many" means? Does that refer to the minimum number of students or the maximum?

Comment: It means that the number of students in the "different" classroom was either equal to the number in the first classroom or greater than the number in the first classroom. It is saying that there were at least the same number of students. That's to say, not less than that number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first classroom had 20 students, and the second classroom has 'at least as many' students, you know that the second classroom has 20 students or more.

'At least as many' in this case means the second classroom has an equal or larger number (math symbol: '>=') of students than the first classroom.